# Select random cell from non-adjacent cells/columns

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, random, google-sheets-formula

I got multiple columns with information. I want to pick a random sentence from 'Mehrzahl' for every row involved. Is it possible to do this with a formula? In the case of Mehrzahl I want to select either E2 or N2 randomly, either E3 or N3 randomly, et cetera.

[image: Example file]

Comment: `randomly` means what? Where do you want to show that selected result?

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing an example of your _manually entered_ desired results there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can flip a coin:

```
=IF(COINFLIP(); E2; N2)
```

[image]

if you want to pick one of each for the whole column:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SORTN(SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF({E2:E, N2:N}="",,
 {E2:E, N2:N}&"×"&ROW(A2:A)&"×"&RANDARRAY(ROWS(A2:A), 2))), 
 "×"), 2, 1, 3, 1), 9^9, 2, 2, 1)),,1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can choose randomly between the value in `E2` and `N2` using `rand()` and `if()`, like this:

`=if( rand() < 0.5, E2, N2 )`